# CSS is working in IE but not in Chrome

Tags: css

My CSS for Modal Popup extender is not working in Chrome, but it works perfectly in IE.

Here is my CSS:

```css
.modalBackground
{
    background-color:#250517;
    opacity:0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
}

.modalPopup 
{
        background-color:White;
        border-width:3px;
        border-style:solid;
        border-color:Black;
        padding:3px;
        width:250px;
        height:300px;

}
```

This is a screenshot of IE, in which the CSS is working perfectly:

[image]

This is a screenshot of Chrome, in which the CSS is not working:

[image]

Comment: 1st screenshot is of IE in which CSS is working perfectly.

Comment: How does the applied CSS look like for that modal popup. You can view the applied CSS in Chrome's dev tools? I'm specifically interested in why doesn't the `height: 300px` value apply...

Comment: 2nd on is of chrome in which CSS is not working.

Comment: it worked fine in my chrome. see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yZWVf/).

Comment: min-height: 300px; will probably do the trick

Comment: it's look like as it is in 1st screenshot. yes I can view the CSS name which I applied in dev tools but the values of back-groundcolor,height is change over there

Comment: @user484458 What are applied values?

Comment: the issue is resolve. there's a issue of history in which previous values are stored, that why it's creating problem. After clearing history it's working perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

```
.modalBackground {
    background: #250517;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}

.modalPopup {
    background: #FFF;
    border: solid 3px #000;
    display: block;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Could you please describe the problem and what you did to fix it (so we don't have to eyeball the difference)? Anyway, it appears you added `display: block;`... probably won't make a difference.

Comment: `display: block;` will make a difference because it forces the element to conform to the set widths and heights. Also, his border in Chrome was gray instead of black because he put `border-color: Black` (note the capital "B").

Comment: @ChrisClower If the modal window wasn't block-level, the height wouldn't apply in IE, too, but it does. Btw, CSS code is *not* case-sensitive - the browsers understand `Black` fine. You can even write CSS like so - `bOdY { cOlOr: ReD; }` - **demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/mksmW/ `:)`

Comment: @ŠimeVidas `bOdY { cOlOr: ReD; }` is ugly and it is crushing nerves! ;)

Comment: @ChrisClower: Judging by the fact that the `width` *does* apply, the element is *already* `block` or `inline-block`. As for the capitalization of `Black` - it's completely irrelevant. Give it a try.

Comment: @minitech I stand corrected, however, my code does work in Chrome, although after looking at ahmadali's answer in jsFiddle, I also see that the OP's original code also works in my version of Chrome. This leads me to believe a.) he's using an old version of Chrome, or more likely b.) there's other code that he didn't post that's interfering somewhere.

Comment: the issue is resolve. there's a issue of history in which previous values are stored, that why it's creating problem. After clearing history it's working perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

It worked fine in my chrome browser. you can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yZWVf/) or [here](http://2bn.ir/50).

your chrome may isn't update. I tried it using chrome 21.

Comment: the issue is resolve. there's a issue of history in which previous values are stored, that why it's creating problem. After clearing history it's working perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

Look, for something like this...there's really no point re-inventing the wheel.

I would strongly recommend a tried and tested plugin that is guaranteed to be cross-browser  and reliable. You'll save yourself so much time and effort.

Try Shadowbox (a jQuery plugin):
http://www.shadowbox-js.com/

Good luck.